# Matrix norm inequality with projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n\times m}$ are two matrices of rank $m$ ($m\leq n$), and $P_{n\times n}$ is any orthogonal projection matrix (not necessarily related to $A$ and $B$). It is known that $\|AP\|\leq\|A\|$ and $\|PB\|\leq\|B\|$ with operator norm. I want to show $\|APB\|\leq\|AB\|$. Can anybody help to prove this or is this wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What do the proofs for the first two inequalities look like and can you adapt those proofs?

Comment: $\|AP\|\leq\|A\|\|P\|=\|A\|$ since $\|P\|=1$, and similarly $\|PB\|\leq\|B\|$. But obviously we cannot use $\|APB\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|\not\leq\|AB\|$...

Comment: I found 2 by 2 matrices A and B and a projection P for which AB=0 but APB is not 0. Post later if you don't find them yourself!

Comment: @Paul Please elaborate... Thanks!

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Paul In your example $A$ and $B$ are not of full (column nor row) rank...

Comment: How about the same P but $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1

\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Or maybe $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &1  & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 &  1& 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$  I guess a construction like this could always be done if $2m\le n$ but maybe not otherwise?